# Liquibase Informix generateChangelog Issue

Tags: database, hibernate, informix, liquibase

I am using Liquibase version 3.3.2 to create a changelog for my existing Informix DB using the generateChangeLog command.

The changelog.xml (483 Kb) is created successfully but contains no changesets! I have tried using other versions of Liquibase but no success. Is it a Liquibase bug?

My command looks like this -

```
liquibase --changeLogFile=changelog.xml --url="jdbc:informix-sqli://172.28.137.182:9088/glsnextgen:informixserver=testgif" --username=abc --password=abc --logLevel=debug --logFile=log.txt --defaultSchema=sysmaster generateChangeLog
```

However, the generated changelog has no changesets. This is what the changelog looks like -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.3.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd"/>
```

This is what my debug log looks like -

```
DEBUG 18/2/15 11:22 AM: liquibase: Connected to santhosh@jdbc:informix-sqli://172.28.137.182:9088/glsnextgen:informixserver=testgif

DEBUG 18/2/15 11:22 AM: liquibase: Setting auto commit to false from true

DEBUG 18/2/15 11:22 AM: liquibase: Executing EXECUTE database command: EXECUTE PROCEDURE IFX_ALLOW_NEWLINE('T');

DEBUG 18/2/15 11:22 AM: liquibase: Computed checksum for 1424238728847 as 9ed2ff6dc6133a2a2bb8f27d79bd1597

INFO 18/2/15 11:22 AM: liquibase: changelog1.xml does not exist, creating

DEBUG 18/2/15 11:22 AM: liquibase: MissingObjectChangeGenerator type order:     liquibase.structure.core.Catalog    liquibase.structure.core.Schema    liquibase.structure.core.Sequence    liquibase.structure.core.StoredProcedure    liquibase.structure.core.Table    liquibase.structure.core.Column    liquibase.structure.core.PrimaryKey    liquibase.structure.core.UniqueConstraint    liquibase.structure.core.ForeignKey    liquibase.structure.core.Index    liquibase.structure.core.View

DEBUG 18/2/15 11:22 AM: liquibase: UnexpectedObjectChangeGenerator type order:     liquibase.structure.core.Catalog    liquibase.structure.core.ForeignKey    liquibase.structure.core.Schema    liquibase.structure.core.StoredProcedure    liquibase.structure.core.UniqueConstraint    liquibase.structure.core.View    liquibase.structure.core.Table    liquibase.structure.core.PrimaryKey    liquibase.structure.core.Column    liquibase.structure.core.Index    liquibase.structure.core.Sequence

DEBUG 18/2/15 11:22 AM: liquibase: ChangedObjectChangeGenerator type order:     liquibase.structure.core.Catalog    liquibase.structure.core.ForeignKey    liquibase.structure.core.Schema    liquibase.structure.core.Sequence    liquibase.structure.core.StoredProcedure    liquibase.structure.core.Table    liquibase.structure.core.Column    liquibase.structure.core.PrimaryKey    liquibase.structure.core.Index    liquibase.structure.core.UniqueConstraint    liquibase.structure.core.View
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that liquibase assumes Informix is always using ansi mode and in that mode the schema is the owner of the table.

then in your parameter --defaultSchemaName=sysmaster  it should be changed to --defaultSchemaName=<owner of tables>

**update**
this works in version 3.4.1 and u can see on the optional parameteres [command line documentation](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html)

Comment: The parameter you mention in your answer does not exist: Unexpected error running Liquibase: Unknown parameter: 'defaultSchema'

Comment: @Michael yes the parameter was wrong I copied the parameter from the text of the question and the correct name is defaultSchemaName